# Randomize jquery return from json data

Tags: c#, jquery, json

Now I no I can call jquery to call my webmethod as such  everty 30 seconds but what I am also wanting to do is page through my records as I have demo data it returns 10 records in the json so what I want to do every 30 seconds is point it to a differnt row its for real time updates i am testing.

Also what is my best method to pass one value from one webservice call to another one is a history table and one is live data I need pass driver id from the first call to a second webservice call.

My question is for demo purposes how would i tell it to go between 1 and 10 of the list data thats returned

```
   var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";
   var webMethod = /Web.asmx/GetTermainalData";
   var parameters = "{'sDate':'" + sDate + "','eDate':'" + eDate + "'}";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(e){
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
    }
});
```

Example Json Data

```
[
{
  "id":157373,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:34:32",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":580.70,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":0,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":0,
  "torque_motor":0,
  "posicao_acelerador":0,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157376,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:34:33",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":578.20,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":0,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":0,
  "torque_motor":0,
  "posicao_acelerador":0,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157390,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:34:43",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":579.10,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":21,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1446,
  "torque_motor":78,
  "posicao_acelerador":23,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157391,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:34:44",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":579.20,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":0,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":0,
  "torque_motor":0,
  "posicao_acelerador":0,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157400,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:34:53",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":579.60,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":24,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1383,
  "torque_motor":77,
  "posicao_acelerador":50,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157413,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:35:03",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":576.00,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":27,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1303,
  "torque_motor":62,
  "posicao_acelerador":48,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157425,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:35:13",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":574.60,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":-20,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1277,
  "torque_motor":63,
  "posicao_acelerador":48,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157438,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:35:23",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":573.80,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":31,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1240,
  "torque_motor":63,
  "posicao_acelerador":48,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157450,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:35:33",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":573.60,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":33,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1216,
  "torque_motor":63,
  "posicao_acelerador":48,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
},
{
  "id":157466,
  "data_atualizacao":"2015-08-02T12:35:43",
  "direcao":0.0,
  "altitude":572.20,
  "id_terminal":5213,
  "temperatura_motor":35,
  "velocidade":0.0,
  "rpm_motor":1209,
  "torque_motor":63,
  "posicao_acelerador":47,
  "nivel_combustivel":0,
  "numero_chassi":"",
  "odometro":15.71,
  "id_motorista":297
}
]
```

Comment: So you want to shuffle the result or reverse it?

Comment: @IrvinDominin hi ideally from the last one to the most recent

Comment: @IrvinDominin so that its going from oldest date time to most recent

Comment: @IrvinDominin i added to the above to show the correct dates

Answer (score 0):

Its easy...

If you want to loop over a list...

```js
var a = {a: 1, b:2, c: 3}

$.each(a, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key, value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thats not exactly what i am wanting I am wanting to show the last item in date order first then in increment of ten seconds move to the next record